# Unable to locate ccgame file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xna

I'm about finished with my project and would like to pack it as a ccgame file, so I right click the project in the solution menu (in VS 2013) to do that. When that finishes, I can't find the ccgame package in any folder. I'd like to know what's going on, if I'm doing something wrong or what.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. SO is not a forum, it is a Q&A site. Ask a specific question and vote for answers you consider good. Finally accept the one answer that you think is **the** answer to your question. You will find more help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).